# Find difference between elements of array?

Tags: javascript

suppose my array is a = [-62,345,10] so i need to find difference of 0 and -62 and  diff of -62 and 345 and then 345 and 10  so on .  How to do this ?

Comment: This is not very complicated to write, what have you tried so far? And what exactly is the desired output? An array of the differences?

Comment: `array[0]=-62; array[1]=345; array[2]=10;`, you want this or?
 `resultarray[0]=array[0]-array[1]; resultarray[1]=array[1]-array[2]`

Comment: please add the wanted result and what you have tried.

Comment: I don't want to sound harsh, but I cannot understand the +1 on a question like this, really.

Answer (score 4):

You could map the difference and take a default value for not given values.

```js
var array = [-62, 345, 10],
    deltas = array.map((v, i, a) => v - (a[i - 1] || 0));
    
console.log(deltas);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
a = [-62, 345, 10];
j = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

  console.log(j - a[i]);
  j = a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map`. For the first index value subtract from 0 and for other indexes, subtract from the previous number.

```js
var a = [-62,345,10];
var result = a.map((n, i, a) => i ? n - a[i-1] : 0 - n);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [-62,345,10];
var result = a.map(function(v, i, a){
 return (i==0 ? 0 : a[i-1]) - a[i]; 
});

console.log(result);
```

Here you go! :)

Answer (score -1):

You could concatenate `[0]` with your array and then map it like:

```js
var arr = [-62,345,10]

var newArr = [0].concat(arr).slice(0, -1).map(function(elem, i) {
  return arr[i] - elem;
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: 345 - 10 == -335 ?

Comment: 10 - 345 = -335